# Can't call static class from different class library?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, static

I'm using the .NET 4 framework, and I have a `static class` with `static functions` in an asp.net web application.

I have a second class library project.  The class library project wants to call the static method in the web application. Intellisense works, but then the compiler reports that

"The name `[MyClassName]` does not exist in the current context".

Can I make this call, or this not allowed?

PS, the static class is in the `/App_Code` folder.

Thanks!

Comment: If you added the class to your an App_Code folder in a Web Application (Not website project) you need to right-click and change the properties to Compile (by default it adds as Content) Also, if you're going from Web App to Class Lib to Web App, you will end up with a circular reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not possible to refactor the class out of the web project?  Referencing a web project from a class library sounds awkward.  If your class does not contain web-specific code then you could pop it into that other class library you mention or create a new one.  Should it reference web-specific libraries something like `MyProject.MyLib.Web` could do the trick.

Comment: excellent point. I'm using a 3rd party CMS and just didn't think through what I'm doing on a larger scope. Either way, I'm guessing that the problem is related to the fact that the static class is not wrapped in a namespace. Does that mean it is not accessible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the project containing the class you want to access.

Comment: I do have a reference to the project

Comment: excellent point. I'm using a 3rd party CMS and just didn't think through what I'm doing on a larger scope. Either way, I'm guessing that the problem is related to the fact that the static class is not wrapped in a namespace. Does that mean it is not accessible? Thanks!

Comment: It _has_ to be in a namespace. It's not accessible if it's `internal`, however.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you are using the full name of the class (including the namespace).

Alternatively add a [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) with the namespace to your code file.

Comment: the static class is not wrapped in a namespace. Does that mean it is not accessible? It's part of a 3rd party CMS and I'm not sure what the implications would be of wrapping it in a namespace since it's already heavily used. Thanks!

Comment: @Joe - Of course it is accessible, how would you using it otherwise. It would be in the global namespace and _can_ be aliased and accessed using the [`global::`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx) syntax for the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If your target framework is `.Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile` change it to `.NET Framework 4` and rebuild the solution.